# Create database in SQL from specific excel files

Tags: sql-server

I am still the newbie in this field so I really appreciate it if you could help me.
This would be my task. I used "Summary" tab as an example.
Every week I get a couple of excel files that have the same format. I need to "edit" that format in format that I need in SQL.
So, in the example you can find 2 sheets: "Summary" and "AAA" and these are the original tabs that I get from my colleagues. Because they are "merged" my first step is to unmerged them and you can see the results of that in sheet "Summary after unmerging". 
After unmerging them, I need to put the data in new "order" and you can see that results in sheet "FINAL Summary table in SQL".
As I said, I have a couple of excel files that I need to "union all" (data) in SQL and create one table.
So, if this, how would I say, first step is doable the next step would be to update this "ONE TABLE" every week form those excel files that I get.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. how to upload excel file here

Comment: You could use the Excel OLEDB driver to access it via SQL. See for instance https://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider/

Comment: import data wizard?

Comment: I would write a bit of vba to unmerge and put int new order in excel